# Rails + Devise: Missing my_sessions translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, translation

Using Devise, I created my own controllers to override the default Devise::XxxController. For example:

```
class Devise::MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    ...

end
```

I inserted all the rewrited Devise controllers in a new folder `controllers/devise/`, and I added the corresponding namespaces in `routes.rb`

Everything is OK, except flash messages, which tells (for example):

`translation missing: en.devise.my_sessions.user.signed_id`

Any idea how to get (again) devise messages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to add the translations to a yml file. The flash messages are looking for them, that particular on would be something like this...

```
en:
 devise:
  my_sessions:
   user:
    signed_id: "Message Here"
```

Here is a link to the [devise yml file](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml) you can copy that.

Comment: But why isn't it reverting to the default translation file inside the Devise gem? What tells it to use `config/locales/en.yml`?